# I have one java problem for moving files one by one by name

Tags: java

I would like to copy my image file by name From `E:\Tejas\FM_Operations\source` to `E:\Tejas\FM_Operations\destination` in a such way that if I call the  `MovePhoto(source,destination,filename)` method, then my image will copied to the destination folder in Java.

Comment: Ok.  So what have you tried already?

Comment: The title talks about multiple files (one by one). The question is just about one file. Note: In Java, you write method calls with small initial. And: Where's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using [`FileUtils.copyFile()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). Otherwise you'll have to copy the bytes manually, like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/src"));
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/dest"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```